# Automated whole application output testing in python

Tags: python, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a script that gets a file input plus some info, runs a couple of (possibly interdependent) programs on it using subprocess module, and distributes the output over the file-system.

Only a few parts can be tested in isolation by traditional unit-testing, so I'm searching a convenient way to automate the integration-testing (see if the output files exist in the right locations, in the right number, of the right size, etc).

I initially thought that `setUp` and `tearDown` methods from the default unittest module could help me, but they are re-run with each test, not once for the entire test suite, so it is not an option. Is there any way to make the unittest module run a global `setUp` and `tearDown` once? Or an alternative module/tool that I can use? Eclipse/PyDev integration would be a bonus.

Comment: There is a test harness that doesn't have those limitations. https://code.google.com/p/pycopia/ Although it's more complicated to set up.

Comment: `nose` is another option.  Written on top of `unittest`, so much of your knowledge should be portable, but adds class, module, and package level setup (as well as other nifty things, like generator test cases).  https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/